# What is the Reporting tool that I will use in APEX?

Tags: reporting, oracle-apex

I'm going to develop a new system using Oracle APEX.
I used to use Oracle Reports Builder to develop reports in Oracle Forms.
What Reporting tool should I use in APEX?
I need something with Oracle Reports features such as Conditional Formatting, PL/SQL support, etc?

Thanks and Regrads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Oracle Reports with Apex - see [this rather old how-to doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/howto-integrate-oracle-reports-097845.html).  Essentially, if you have Reports set up to run via the web then you can run a report via a URL like this:

http://myserver:7777/reports/rwservlet?report=myreport.jsp&userid=myuser/mypassword@mydb&desformat=pdf&destype=cache&p_empno=1234

So it is then just a matter of constructing this URL in Apex and using it.  You can avoid passing the password as a parameter by using single sign-on for Apex and Reports.

See [Quick Start Guide to Oracle Reports Server 9.0.4](http://www.rittmanmead.com/files/quick_start_guide_oracle_reports.html) for further details.

The recommended approach I think is to use BI Publisher, but that is expensive to license.  There may be cheaper third-party alternatives to BI Publisher that can be used, but I don't know them.

I think there are a number of people in the Apex community waiting for a nice solution to this requirement!

Comment: Thanks, Eng. Tony, to be honest this is a weak point in APEX, as my system requirements contain many reports, can I ask which tool did you use in Northengate?, also if I used BI publisher, can I integrate or run its reports from APEX?    Thanks and regards

Comment: I can't remember quite how we did it at Northgate, but I now recall that quite recently I worked with Forms and Reports 10G, and running reports was simply a matter of constructing the appropriate URL - so this will obviously work fine with Apex too.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have that in APEX forms with PL/SQL. But you have to be more specific or you can try in http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html creating a workspace and see what can be done with APEX.